# using and operator for constant order type values

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Experts ,I've one issue where I want to combine two constant values while checking if statement. One order type with IF is working but I need to check two order types.Both have same products list.

Existing code-working for one order type

```
 if (SF_OrderType_textBox.Text == "HHC Medicaid");
        {
            SF_Addl_Product_textBox.Text = PopulateNextField(Addl_Products_List, SF_Addl_Product_textBox.Text);
        }
```

want to achieve below with two order types-But not working

```
 if (SF_OrderType_textBox.Text == "HHC Medicaid"&"HHC Rentals");
        {
            SF_Addl_Product_textBox.Text = PopulateNextField(Addl_Products_List, SF_Addl_Product_textBox.Text);
        }
```

this AND(&) operator is not working. Can you please advise whats the correct syntax for this?

Thanks

Comment: How could value of a textbox be "HHC Medicaid" and "HHC Rentals" at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform logic AND `&` with two strings then the condition will always be false, yes?

```cs
(a == "a" & a == "b")
```

> False

Maybe you are looking for logic OR `|`

```cs
(a == "a" | a == "b")
```

> True

Also look at short-circuiting the OR `||`

```cs
(a == "a" || a == "b")
```

> True, but only evaluates first statement because OR condition is met

Apply it to your code, simplys

```cs
if (SF_OrderType_textBox.Text == "HHC Medicaid" || SF_OrderType_textBox.Text == "HHC Rentals");
```

If you could have a list of those HHC types you could put them in an array to make your code more extensible.

```cs
var hhcTypes = new string[] { "HHC Medicaid", "HHC Rentals" };
if (hhcTypes.Contains(SF_OrderType_textBox.Text))
```